# Serverless - use same bucket from other stack in my current stack

Tags: serverless-framework

I've 2 stacks running on serverless using AWS Cloud and I want to share S3 Bucket between stack A and stack B.

On stack A, I have exported the output as follow:

```
Outputs:
  EvidenceEventsBucketName:
    Value:
      Ref: EvidenceEventsKinesisFirehoseBucket          
    Export:
      Name: ${self:service}-evidences-events-bucket-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
```

And on stack B, I'm trying to import it:

```
evidenceDataSent:
  handler: evidences.handlers.process_sent_events
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 900      
  events:
    - s3:
        bucket: 
          Fn::ImportValue: 'twilio-stream-kinesis-evidences-events-bucket-prod'
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
        rules:
          - prefix: raw/
```

Something is wrong because when I try to deploy it, I got the following error:

```
Type Error ---------------------------------------------

name.replace is not a function
```

How can I share a bucket between stacks?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have exported and then imported should work. I could be wrong, but your Fn:Import looks odd compared to how I do it. Try the shortened syntax instead:

```
bucket: !ImportValue twilio-stream-kinesis-evidences-events-bucket-prod
```